# Is there a way to select specific characters from a TextView variable?

Tags: java, android, textview

I am using AWS IoT to read and publish some information from a microelectronic's sensors. I am able to get the json file in the app as a big wall of text, but it is not very readable. I am using TextView as I don't want the user to be able to change the information. My problem is that I can't find a way to remove the parts that are not necessary to the user.

I am new to app creation, so I am trying to do this as simply as possible. I have my xml ready to receive the information; I just need the info in a variable that I can pass to it. I have tried implementing a character array, but haven't been able to get past the fact that I can't edit the text view.

```java
        tvLastMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLastMessage);
```

This is currently the block of text that I am receiving. It looks like this:

```
{"sensors":[{"name":"steamTemp","data":"181.39","state":1,
{"name":"waterTemp","data":"-713.15","state":0,
{"name":"waterFlow","data":"0.00","state":3,
{"name":"dieselFlow","data":"0.00","state":2,
{"name":"manualResetLevel","data":"1","state":0,
{"name":"waterFeederLevel","data":"1","state":0,
{"name":"autoResetPressure","data":"1","state":0,
{"name":"manualResetPressure","data":"1","state":0},
{"name":"tempLimit","data":"1","state":0,
{"name":"heatEff","data":"0.00","state":2}]}
```

The text does not look as formatted as this, but it is more understandable and readable to represent it this way. It normally does not have the new lines, so it will just naturally go to one as it runs out of room.

I am hoping that I can get it to simply show the numbers associated with each "name" and "data" as I have those hard-coded into my xml since they don't change. Just getting those numbers into different variables would be ideal, so I can simply reference the variable in my xml file. However, if there is a better way to do this, I am happy to take suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a loop to find each instance of "name", "data", and "state", and get the values between them.

Assuming input is a string:

```
String string = "{\"sensors\":[{\"name\":\"steamTemp\",\"data\":\"181.39\",\"state\":1,\n{\"name\":\"waterTemp\",\"data\":\"-713.15\",\"state\":0,\n{\"name\":\"waterFlow\",\"data\":\"0.00\",\"state\":3,\n{\"name\":\"dieselFlow\",\"data\":\"0.00\",\"state\":2,\n{\"name\":\"manualResetLevel\",\"data\":\"1\",\"state\":0,\n{\"name\":\"waterFeederLevel\",\"data\":\"1\",\"state\":0,\n{\"name\":\"autoResetPressure\",\"data\":\"1\",\"state\":0,\n{\"name\":\"manualResetPressure\",\"data\":\"1\",\"state\":0},\n{\"name\":\"tempLimit\",\"data\":\"1\",\"state\":0,\n{\"name\":\"heatEff\",\"data\":\"0.00\",\"state\":2}]}";
Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<>();

int index0 = 0, index1, index2;

while (true) {
    // Get indices
    index0 = string.indexOf("name", index0);
    index1 = string.indexOf("data", index0);
    index2 = string.indexOf("state", index1);

    // If "name", "data", or "state" was not found
    if (index0 == -1 || index1 == -1 || index2 == -1)
        break;

    // Get the data from the string and put it into the map
    String key = string.substring(index0 + 7, index1 - 3);
    Double value = Double.parseDouble(string.substring(index1 + 7, index2 - 3));
    map.put(key, value);

    // Update index
    index0 = index2;
}

System.out.println(map);
```

Output:

```
{waterFlow=0.0, manualResetLevel=1.0, waterFeederLevel=1.0, manualResetPressure=1.0, waterTemp=-713.15, autoResetPressure=1.0, tempLimit=1.0, dieselFlow=0.0, heatEff=0.0, steamTemp=181.39}
```